# Get absolute path of the script directory that is being processed by Job DSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, dsl

I have a DSL groovy script defining a pipeline job. I need to load Jenkinsfile from the workspace. The Jenkinsfile resides in the same folder as that of the groovy script. I am trying to get the path of the groovy script programmatically so that I can use that to figure out the path of the Jenkinsfile and load it using `readFileFromWorkspace`. I tried using `__FILE__` directive after going through the [job-dsl-wiki](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands#script-location). But I am getting the following error:

```
Processing provided DSL script
ERROR: (test_job.groovy, line 3) No such property: absolutePath for class: java.lang.String
Finished: FAILURE
```

Here is my DSL script

```
job_name = "my-pipeline-job"
job_path = "${new File(__FILE__).parent.absolutePath}"
jenkinsfile = job_path + "/Jenkinsfile"
pipelineJob(job_name){
 description("Jenkins pipeline job")
 parameters{
  stringParam("MyTestParam", "", "a sample parameter")
 }
 definition {
   cps {
      sandbox()
      script(readFileFromWorkspace(jenkinsfile))
   }
 }
}
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong here? Really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Ok , figured out the solution. it should be `job_path = "${new File(__FILE__).parent}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation in the wiki is a little misleading. Here is the working solution.

```
job_name = "my-pipeline-job"
println "Script: ${ __FILE__}"
println("script directory: ${new File(__FILE__).parent}")
job_path = "${new File(__FILE__).parent}"
jenkinsfile = job_path + "/Jenkinsfile"
pipelineJob(job_name){
 description("Jenkins pipeline job")
 parameters{
   stringParam("MyTestParam", "", "a sample parameter")
 }
 definition {
   cps {
      sandbox()
      script(readFileFromWorkspace(jenkinsfile))
   }
 }
}
```